# How to make activity wait for zxing scanner to finish?

Tags: java, android, wait, zxing

Within my app, I have an activity which uses zxing barcode scanner. All of the code I want to execute after the scan I have to move to `onActivityResult(...)`, because the program continues execution with the lines after `canIntegrator.initiateScan();` even before scanner finishes.

Is there a way to make application wait for zxing to finish before continuing execution?

Answer (score 1):

use startActivity for result like below

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I do this? I am starting the scanner with scanIntegrator.initiateScan(); not with the startActivity(). ?

Comment: search for samples on zxing you will get some idea

Answer (score 0):

If you run the scan in a Thread you could join the Thread so you get back to your main Programm thread when the scan is done successfully or not  (shouldn't be the UI thread otherwise you would block it)